# Accessing attribute name containing slash in javascript object

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I'm trying to access an js object property which has an slash "/" in its name.

The object its somthing like:

```
{
   my/key : "my value"
   // more stuff here...
}
```

I try the following construction:

```
myObject["my/key"]
```

If I try to it in Chrome DevTools it works correctly but when I execute my code i get a beautiful undefined on browser console (using console.log())

has anybody any idea of what's happening? :S

Comment: Try using backslash before slash, this could help.

Comment: / is not an illegal character - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names for a comprehensive description of what is valid.

Comment: Pretty much anything can go into property name (including newlines for example `a = {}; a["\n"] = 'foo';` works) as long as you enclose it in quotes and use array access operator. JS objects are key-value maps essentially, and keys can be anything.

Answer (score 8):

When you enclose the prop name into quotes, it works also in the code:

```
var obj = {
    'my/key' : 'my value'
};
```

You can check this at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jy4Dd/).

Comment: This is what you want to do; without quotes, it's a division operator.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in Node.js and it is working as expected, as long as the property name is quoted.

Try outputting the exact value of the key ("my/key") that you use to access the value - maybe, you are using a different key there.